# Export SELECT Statement to Excel within Query

Tags: sql, excel, select, export

So I need to export this SELECT statement to an excel file (lets say to my desktop) but I need it to be done within the query so it kicks out a new file each time (overwrites it) the script is run from start to finish. SSIS is not an option, nor is a standard export. See SELECT statement below.

```
SELECT
    Sub_Company,
    GL_Account,
    CAST(SUM(Debits) AS DECIMAL(18,2)) AS Debits,
    CAST(SUM(Credits) AS DECIMAL(18,2)) AS Credits,
    CAST(SUM([P&L_Impact]) AS DECIMAL(18,2)) AS [P&L_Impact],
    COUNT(*) AS Record_Count
FROM
(
    SELECT *
    FROM [FL_SQL_Training].[dbo].[Combined_GL]
    WHERE
        Company = 'US' AND
        GL_Source = 'Consolidation'
) A
WHERE
    GL_Journal_Header_Description LIKE '%UK%' OR
    GL_Journal_Header_Description LIKE '%CAD%' OR
    GL_Journal_Header_Description LIKE '%MEX%' OR
    GL_Journal_Header_Description LIKE '%Hon%'
GROUP BY
    Sub_Company,
    GL_Account
```

Thanks,

Comment: What exactly constitutes a "standard export" that isn't allowed? You can't actually do stuff "within" a query.

Comment: Things like the export wizard, copy/paste, etc. There's no export command in SQL Server? I thought there was a way to use OUTPUT and call the excel drivers in SQL.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    Sub_Company,
    GL_Account,
    CAST(SUM(Debits) AS DECIMAL(18,2)) AS Debits,
    CAST(SUM(Credits) AS DECIMAL(18,2)) AS Credits,
    CAST(SUM([P&L_Impact]) AS DECIMAL(18,2)) AS [P&L_Impact],
    COUNT(*) AS Record_Count
    INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/accounts.csv'
    FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
    ENCLOSED BY '"'
    LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';
FROM
(
    SELECT *
    FROM [FL_SQL_Training].[dbo].[Combined_GL]
    WHERE
        Company = 'US' AND
        GL_Source = 'Consolidation'
) A
WHERE
    GL_Journal_Header_Description LIKE '%UK%' OR
    GL_Journal_Header_Description LIKE '%CAD%' OR
    GL_Journal_Header_Description LIKE '%MEX%' OR
    GL_Journal_Header_Description LIKE '%Hon%'
GROUP BY
    Sub_Company,
    GL_Account
```

Comment: There's an error on the "A" table alias line. Not sure where else to put this.

Answer (score 0):

Create the excel data source and insert the values,

```
insert into OPENROWSET('Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0', 
'Excel 8.0;Database=D:\testing.xls;', 
'SELECT * FROM [SheetName$]') select * from SQLServerTable
```

More informations are available here http://www.sqlteam.com/forums/topic.asp?TOPIC_ID=49926

Comment: Kicks out an error sadly: OLE DB provider 'Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0' cannot be used for distributed queries because the provider is configured to run in single-threaded apartment mode.

Comment: You have to enable openrowset , since it is disabled for security reasons: 

sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1;
RECONFIGURE;
sp_configure 'Ad Hoc Distributed Queries', 1;
RECONFIGURE;
GO

Comment: Consider also the idea to put your query in a view and to create an excel file that points directly to the view, this is the best way to connect Excel to SQL server.